# CSS Border on three sides

Tags: css, border

If i want to have border on the three sides, do I need to declare border for each side eg.

```
border-left:1px solid green;
border-bottom:1px solid green;
border-right:1px solid green;
```

or is there any shortcut way?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

```
border: 1px solid green;
border-top: 0;
```

Comment: did you see it working in *any* browser? I'm on a mac and it didn't work in safari, chrome, or firefox

Answer (score 17):

Well, there is a *slightly* shorter way - but it's not what you'd call a shortcut...

```
border: 1px solid green;
border-top: 0;
```

Or you could declare partial elements which would allow for clarity:

```
border-color: green;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 0 1px 1px 1px;
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to declare the border-top `style` and then override it:

```
border: 1px green;
border-style: none solid solid;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
border:1px solid green;
border-top: none;
```

Note: I wouldn't do this myself, personally; it could be confusing to those reading it, and there's really no need. Although the original way involves repetition, it's minimal.

Answer (score 2):

this is a little shorter and does the same:

```
border:1px solid green;
border-top:0;
```