# CSS property - set global border first, and then specify border-bottom?

Tags: css, border, semantics

What is the best CSS practice to achieve a `border` on all sides of a container, apart from, for example, the bottom?

The `border` property cannot specify different values for each side.

**Option 1:** Overwriting Rules

```
border: 1px solid red;
border-bottom: none;
```

- Seems that an extra computation is needed — similar drawbacks as CSS resets (at least philosophically).

**Option 2:** Setting Specific Rules

```
border-top: 1px solid red;
border-left: 1px solid red;
border-right: 1px solid red;
```

- Might be more correct (in terms of CSS "semantics")
- But if you want to change the border specifics, then it'll require
  multiple changes (harder to manage).

Comment: I'd alway use option one but that's just me and my experience I'm not 100% sure on which practise is best.

Comment: Same here, but I like to question simple things sometimes :P

Comment: Same its always best to find the correct/best methods

Comment: Option one allows less redundancy. Of course, it also overrides any existing styles for `border-bottom`, which option two does not. So the answer is: whichever approach is best for your particular case.

Comment: Remember: CSS has no notion of semantics. That said, I would definitely go with Option 1 - use the cascade and the huge flexibility of `border` properties to your advantage! There's no need to worry about browser performance in microscopic issues such as this. CSS resets present a slightly more significant problem as they apply styles to as many elements as possible, which is quite different.

Comment: Here's my approach: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22124065/478018

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it totally depends on you, what is more convenient to you, it also depends on some state like if I want the `color` of all borders to be same I'll go for 1st but If I think I need to change the colors of each side of the border in near future I'll go with the second 1, but for now, I'll stick to first option

Reasons:

- Less CSS to be stated
- Specifically it shows that I want `border-bottom` as `none`
- As you said I don't need to change each and every `property: value` if I need any changes

If you say proper semantics, proper semantics define very specifically like

```
border-color: /*Whatever*/;
border-width: /*Whatever*/;
border-style: /*Whatever*/;
```

Now am sure you don't want to be this specific

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to specify the values once, you can specify the color and width for all, then the style specifically for the sides:

```
border-color: red;
border-width: 1px;
border-style: solid solid none solid;
```

Comment: Interesting solution, and if anyone is wondering: yes, `border-style` does allow such usage: http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/border-style — however, it still sets `red` and `1px` for the border that shouldn't have anything